# How to clean off hands oil from a touchscreen?

Tags: cleaning, technology

I don't find [anything here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/166/cleaning-a-dirty-computer-screen) that would help to my situation, and wiping the screen don't seems to remove the oil that has gotten trough my hands. I need a method without baby wipes which I don't posses, nor socks (or any cotton cloth), I don't possess glasses cleaning cloths (I had one years ago), nor any other recommendation is readly available to clean off the screen safely.

The mentioned [suggestions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/166/cleaning-a-dirty-computer-screen) don't solve my problem. The other question is asking about **dust**, mine is **oil** (or grease) which most of dust methods are helpless about.

Comment: Since having kids I think I will always buy baby wipes as they are so useful. Cleaning glasses, screens etc just have to be careful not to let the dog eat them though!

Comment: @shog as I mentioned in chat, I read that question but neither the objetive of the question nor the answers are particualry helpful here and the solutions are actually **very obvious** which I already tried/think about and discarded.

Comment: @NickJAdams I don't have kids, and baby wipes are too costly (imported is the only way) to having a stash to clean the screen constantly.

Comment: Perhaps the best prevention is INTERVENTION... stop TOUCHING your screen with your dirty hands hands. If it isn't a touch device, you should NEVER touch the screen. If it IS a touch device, clean your fingertips (not sure why whole hands are touching the screen) before use. Simply wiping them on your pants or shirt should do the trick.

Comment: Using a microfiber cloth will take care of hand oil as well as dust, so the question marked as duplicate does answer your question

Comment: @holroy no, it doesn't. The other answers *just doesn't work* for **my** situation, since I just **don't possess microfiber** which was explained in the post. More on the topic [What to do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253925)

Comment: @Phlume if everybody that touch the screen did, that would work.

Comment: Hmmm, this still kind of becomes a duplicate question as most people do have either microfiber clothes or some cotton cloth or piece of cotton fabric, which all can be used to clean the screen. I would either try to get/but  microfiber cloths, or use some cotton fabric.

Comment: @holroy "most people" doesn't mean that you can brush off my own circumstances. I have cotton cloths but that doesn't remove the greases, it only disseminates it, so it isn't a solution to my problem, it *doesn't remove the grease*. Microfiber, on the other hand, is so rare to find here, that you can call it a luxury item.

Comment: I'm sorry if you are offended by my remarks, but remember that this is a community with questions and answers for the community albeit asked by individuals. Have you tried applying a small amount of dish washer to your cloth, this could pick up/remove the oil. Do be careful not to apply to much, as you must probably know that screens and fluids are not the best combination...

Comment: I added another [answer](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/6254/4490) to the other thread, as this is closed. If interested, please do comment on that answer, as to if it is helpful or not. I've used those trick myself on similar devices